# append values to csv file

Tags: python, csv, append

Folks, I am trying to append data including following 4 properties: `name`, `id`, `height` and `length` to a csv file. The code I wrote can give me the result but all showing up in one row (see pic below). Is there anyway I can put every person in a new row? I tried but could not figure out and I did not find similar answers on this forum.

Thank you.

```py
# codes for append data to csv file.
def inputappend():
    name=raw_input("input name: ")
    id=raw_input("input ID ")
    height=raw_input("inut height: ")
    length=raw_input("input length ")

    with open('namelist.csv','a') as csvfile:
         csvfile.write(name+','+ id+ ','+ height+ ','+ length+ ',')         
         csvfile.close()
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a line separator, `\n`, (or from the Python os package, [`os.linesep`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep)) on every call to `write`:

```
csvfile.write(name+','+ id+ ','+ height+ ','+ length+ '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way you can do this - using `csv` module: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: Seems like a lot of overhead for such a simple insert.

Comment: yeah... but line endings is not everything you need to care about. so it's better to build csv using tools that are built for that kind of job... But yeah - if this is one time script to create csv from known data - its ok to just append `\n`.